# Checking a list against different criteria rules

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given a list of items, I want to create a function to check if it matches a certain criteria and return true or false.

Here is an example of the criteria and expected output:

```
    #the to check against with criteria[1]
    langList = ['spanish','english','russian','persian']

    criteria = ['any'] #matches any language
    result: match

    #langList does not contain one or all
    criteria = ['any-but-or',[english,chinese]] 
    result: no match

    #langList does not contain all
    criteria = ['any-but-and',[english,chinese]] 
    result: match

    #langList contains one or all
    criteria = ['any-with-or',[english,chinese]] 
    result: match

    #langList contains all
    criteria = ['any-with-and',[english,chinese]] 
    result: no match

    #langList contains one or all and no others
    criteria = ['only-with-or',[english,chinese]] 
    result: no match

    #langList contains all and no others
    criteria = ['only-with-and',[english,chinese]] 
    result: no match
```

What's the best way to do this?
My idea is something like below but I'm haven't mastered list comprehension yet which I think is key here.

```
    def check_criteria_match(criteria, languageList):

        rule = criteria[0]
        criteriaLanguages = criteria[1]
        match = True

        if rule != 'any':
            continue
        elif rule = 'any-but-or' #check languageList:
            match = False; break

        #[...]

        return match
```

***EDIT:***
Based on Praveen Gollakota's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229168/1045235), here is the final function, isn't she pretty :)

```
def check_rule(rule, o, p):
    # o = original, p = pattern
    if rule == 'any':
        return True
    elif rule == 'any-but-or':
        return not bool(set(p)-set(o))
    elif rule == 'any-but-and':
        return len(set(p)-set(o)) != 0
    elif rule == 'any-with-or':
        return len(set(p)-set(o)) <= 1
    elif rule == 'any-with-and':
        return len(set(p)-set(o)) == 0
    elif rule == 'only-with-or':
        return len(set(o)-set(p)) <= 1
    elif rule == 'only-with-and':
        return len(set(o)-set(p)) == 0
```

Comment: Where do you need to read the criteria from?  Do they only appear in your program source, or in configuration files, or from user input?

Comment: Each user in database will have his own criteria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do membership testing, for which `sets` are the appropriate data structures and `set` operations work well.

You can use sets and lambda functions to build a rule based dispatcher like this.

```
>>> rule_checker = {'any': lambda o, p: True, 
...                 'any-but-or': lambda o, p: not bool(set(p) - set(o)),
...                 'any-but-and': lambda o, p: len(set(p) - set(o)) != 0,}

>>> lang_list = ['spanish','english','russian','persian']
>>> rule_checker['any-but-and'](lang_list, ['english','chinese'])
True
>>> rule_checker['any-but-or'](lang_list, ['english','chinese'])
False
```

Of course, you need to add the rest of the rules in there.

EDIT: You can also write the rules inside a function like this.

```
>>> def check_rule(rule, o, p):
...     # o = original, p = pattern
...     if rule == 'any':
...         return True
...     elif rule == 'any-but-or':
...         return not bool(set(p)-set(o))
...     elif rule == 'any-but-and':
...         return len(set(p)-set(o)) != 0
... 
>>> check_rule('any-but-and', lang_list, ['english','chinese'])
True
```

Comment: @ofko Instead of a dict based dispatcher, you can embed all the rules in a function if you like. But the main point is that you don't need *list comprehensions* to do your task.  You want to do simple membership testing for which sets are the way to go.

Comment: Please refer to Python documentation on [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html#set-objects). The operations are really easy. Writing the rest of the rules will be good practice.

Comment: the above function wrongly returned False for:
`check_rule('any-but-or', ['spanish','english','russian','persian'], ['english','chinese'])`
so I think you meant `return bool(set(p)-set(o))` without the 'now' right?

Comment: You wanted to return a `no match` for `any-but-or` in your question. And this function returns `False` which is the same as `no match`. I just wrote the function to adhere to what you wrote in the question. If the original question is not stated correctly, you need to modify the logic as needed.

Comment: Oh my fault it was False was correct. Effects of not getting adequet sleep I think. *get's coffee and goes back to coding*

Comment: Thanks Praveen, it's a very concise approach, I can see me using set more ofter :)

Comment: If you found the approach useful, consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a library like [asq](https://code.google.com/p/asq/):

> **asq** is a simple implementation of a [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)-inspired API for Python which
>   operates over Python iterables, including a parallel version
>   implemented in terms of the Python standard library multiprocessing
>   module. The API sports feature equivalence with LINQ for objects, 100%
>   statement test coverage and [comprehensive documentation](http://docs.asq.googlecode.com/hg/1.0/html/index.html).

### Examples

```
>>> from asq.initiators import query
>>> langList = ['spanish', 'english', 'russian', 'persian']

# langlist contains 'russian'
>>> query(langList).contains('russian')
True

# langlist contains 'english' or 'italian'
>>> query(langList).any(lambda x : x == 'english' or x == 'italian')
True

# langlist contains 'english' and 'russian'
>>> not query(('english', 'russian')).difference(langList).any()
True
```